# Capybara using xpath with I18n to find a button

Tags: button, xpath, capybara, railstutorial.org

I'm using the M. Hartl's Tutorial to create my app, and I'm stucked with some buttons. I want to apply [this tests](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users?version=4.0#code-follow_unfollow_button_tests) to my own buttons, but I can't figure out how to adapt this line.

```rb
it { should have_xpath("//input[@value='Unfollow']") }
```

To this button :

```rb
<%= form_for(product, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :sharable, value: nil %></div>
  <%= f.submit t('button.product.sharable.undo'), class: "btn btn-info btn-small" %>
<% end %>
```

Or this button :

```rb
<%= form_for(current_user.future_ownerships.build(product_id: product.id),
                                                  remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :product_id %></div>
  <%= f.submit t('button.ownership.create'), class: "btn btn-success btn-small" %>
<% end %>
```

I tried something like :

```rb
it { should have_xpath("//input[@value='t('button.ownership.create')']") }
```

But as I thought, I'm syntactically failing :

```rb
 Nokogiri::XML::XPath::SyntaxError:
   Invalid predicate: //input[@value='t('button.ownership.create')']
```

Do you have any idea how to do it ? Is it even possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You're not executing the `t(...)` function (I guess it's a Ruby function in here, which does the I18N), which is probably not exported to Nokogiri (and anyway wouldn't be called either).

```
"//input[@value='" + t('button.ownership.create') + "']"
```